# Bit strings of length 7 with restrictions...

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be the set of bit strings of length $7$, and let $x$ be the bit string $0100111$. Let $S_0$ be the set of bit strings of $S$ which agree with $x$ in the first $2$ bits, but not in the last $2$ bits, and let $S_1$ be the set of bit strings of $S$ which agree with $x$ in the last $2$ bits, but not in the first two bits. Let $S_2$ be the bit strings of $S$ not contained in $S_0$ or $S_1$. What is the size of $S_2$, ie. $\vert S_2 \rvert$?

To solve this I know that there are $2^7 = 128$ bit strings in $S$.

$S_0 = 01???00 = 2^3 = 8$ bit strings

$S_1 = 10???11 = 2^3 = 8$ bit strings.

So $S_2$ must have $128 - 8 - 8 = 112$ bit strings. But the answer choices are $76$, $78$, $72$, $74$ and $80$.

I'm clearly missing something and I would really appreciate the help!
Thanks...

Comment: Your counts are wrong. To be in $S_0$, say, you need to match in the first two but differ in the last (not match).  Hence the first two slots are fixed, but the last two can be one of three possibilities ($00,10, 01$).  Hence $2^3*3=24$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!! Thanks!!!